# Dynamically add tspan to g element depending on attribute in data in d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg, nvd3.js

I want to add `tspan` to `g` element depending on attribute present in d or not.

```
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),     links = tree.links(nodes);

  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")    .attr("class", "node")     .attr("transform", function(d) { 
          return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

 nodeEnter.selectAll('g.user-info')
    .append('tspan');//how can i dynamically add tspan to g
```

I tried the following:

```
 nodeEnter.selectAll('g.user-info')
    .append('tspan',function(d){ if d.id==1 return " " else return "tspan"});/
```

But it does not work, as it adds `tspan` irrespective of the given condition.

Answer (score 1):

Use a .[filter](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_filter):

```
nodeEnter.selectAll('g.user-info')
  .filter(function(d){
    return d.id === 1;
  })
  .append('tspan');
```

Multiple tspan based on property:

Anytime I hear a variable number of based on data, I think [nested-selection](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/).  For instance, here's a quick example of a variable number of `tspan` based on a property "role":

```js
var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', 500)
  .attr('height', 500);
  
var data = [{role: "one"},{role: "two"},{role: "three"}];

var tE = svg.selectAll('text')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('text');
  
tE.selectAll('tspan')
  .data(function(d){
    switch(d.role){
      case "one":
        return d3.range(1);
        break;
      
      case "two":
        return d3.range(2);
        break;
      
      case "three":
        return d3.range(3);
        break;
    }
  })
  .enter()
  .append("tspan")
  .text(function(d){ return d });
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

Comment: @ mark thanks that works but what to do if i have to attach multiple tspan for example based on role of person i want to show color in node and a person can have multiple roles